# How to execute first and then return value from AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask which does some work and returns a boolean value.

```
private class SyncSaleable extends AsyncTask<ItemSaleable, Void, Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ChooseState.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(ItemSaleable... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            JSONObject syncJSON = userFunctions.setToSaleable(params[0]);
            if(syncJSON.has("success"))
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

I'm not sure I'm currently executing this the correct way. I'm executing this like this

```
boolean state = new SyncTransToDealer().execute(item).get();
if(state){
    //Do some work here
}
```

Why I'm saying this is because the `onPreExecute` and `onPostExecute` are not executing, as in the progress dialog is missing.

Comment: what is the meaning of .execute(item).get(); ??

Comment: I saw it from one of the questions asked in here and it returned the boolean value I required from the AsyncTask. I need to look at what Michal has suggested below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use this code

```
if(state){
    //Do some work here
}
```

in `onPostExecute` like

```
if(result){
//Do some work here
}
```

and only this `new SyncTransToDealer().execute(item)` on your `onCreat` or in  other method you're using. Make sure you've provided related permission in `manifest`

Answer (score 3):

Look into the documentation what `.get()` means [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29) it's not asynchronous and it blocks calling thread as it waits for result. Remove that get method from execution.